# Parsear Geo URI en Java

Tags: java, regex

Necesito parsear una URI de tipo geo.

Muestras:

1. `geo:79.786971,-124.399677`
2. `geo:42.374260,-71.120824?z=16`

Para el primera muestra tengo la expresión regular para filtrar que su estructura sea correcta:

```
^geo:.(\\-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?),\\s*(\\-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)$
```

Para el segundo que hay el añadido de `?=z` no me salgo. Los valores del zoom son enteros de 0 a 99.

Para separar los datos, como solo necesito los valores numéricos, uso:

```
s = "geo:79.786971,-124.399677?z=16";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(">> "+ m.group());
}
```

Su resultado:

```
79.786971
-124.399677
16
```

Resumiendo:

- Detectar si es un `geo:lat,lon` o `geo:lat,lon?z=16`
- obtener en variables `lat` `lon` y, si hay, `?z=` pues `zoom`

Comment: Zoom sería siempre `[0-9]+`?

Comment: los valores del zoom son enteros de 0 a 99

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Expresión regular**

Se puede validar y capturar todo con un único regex:

```
^geo:([-+]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?),([-+]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:\?z=(\d{1,2}))?$
```

[Demo en RegexPlanet.com](http://fiddle.re/yyyyyu6tkyr)

**Descripción**

El único concepto importante a entender acá son los grupos.
En regex, los paréntesis simples (también llamados [**grupos capturadores**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg)) tienen 2 funciones: agrupar y capturar.

1. Agrupar.
   Funcionan como un agrupador de un subpatrón. Y así, permiten separar construcciones o repetir una parte específica.

   > Por ejemplo, `(subpatrón){3}` sirve para repetir el *subpatrón* 3 veces.
2. Capturar.
   El texto con el que coincide un grupo es capturado y devuelto luego de la coincidencia. En Java, se obtienen las capturas de cada grupo con [`Matcher.group(int group)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group-int-).

   Luego de llamar a `Matcher.find()`, el texto capturado por el primer conjunto de paréntesis se obtiene con `Matcher.group(1)`, el del segundo grupo con `Matcher.group(2)`, y así sucesivamente. Además, el caso especial de `Matcher.group(0)` (o `Matcher.group()` sin pasar el parámetro) devuelve la coincidencia de toda la expresión regular.

   > Por ejemplo, si usamos el regex `desde (\d+) hasta (\d+)` y coincide, `Matcher.group()` contendrá todo el texto con el que coincidió, y obtendremos cada uno de los 2 números en `Matcher.group(1)` y `Matcher.group(2)`.

   Los grupos siempre se cuentan de izquierda a derecha.
   *El grupo* N *será el* N-ésimo `(` *abierto en el regex.*

Por otro lado, también existen [**grupos sin captura**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html?is-external=true#special), cuya sintaxis es `(?:subpatrón)`
Tienen la misma función de agrupar que los paréntesis simples, pero en este caso no capturan el texto.

- > Por ejemplo, el regex `desde (\d+(?:\.\d+)?) hasta (\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` nos 
  >   permite tener los dos números con la parte decimal opcional (porque la parte decimal está 
  >   agrupada y repetida 0 o 1 vez con el `?`). No obstante, seguimos teniendo sólo 2 grupos 
  >   capturadores y cada número es devuelto con `Matcher.group(1)` y `Matcher.group(2)`.

Una buena práctica es usar grupos sin captura siempre que no se necesite obtener esa parte del texto, para evitar usar memoria innecesaria. Además, es más sencillo para quien esté leyendo tu regex, porque queda claro que estás agrupando pero no te interesa recuperar esa parte.
<sub>-*Ya sé, al principio cuesta leer esos `?` y `:` de más, que no es un cuantificador, pero te aseguro que en poco tiempo se lee de corrido y se comprende automáticamente*.</sub>

Una vez entendido esto, es muy sencillo interpretar el regex de esta respuesta.

`^geo:([-+]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?),([-+]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:\?z=(\d{1,2}))?$`

- `^` ::: Coincide con la posición inicial del string.
- `geo:` ::: Literal.
- `([-+]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` ::: **Grupo 1** - Un número real.

  - `[-+]?` ::: signo `-` o `+` opcional
  - `\d+` ::: parte entera
  - `(?:\.\d+)?` ::: parte decimal opcional (está agrupada y con el [cuantificador](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html?is-external=true#greedy) `?`).
- `,` ::: Literal.
- `([-+]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` ::: **Grupo 2** - Otro real.
- `(?:\?z=(\d{1,2}))?` ::: grupo sin captura opcional - el zoom.

  - `\?z=` ::: literal `?z=`
  - `(\d{1,2})` - **Grupo 3** - Entero entre 0 y 99

    > Pero como este grupo está dentro de otro grupo opcional, cuando no tenga zoom, `Matcher.group(3)` va a devolver *`null`*.
- `$` ::: Coincide con la posición final del string.

---

**Código**

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

```java
final String  s = "geo:42.374260,-71.120824?z=16";
final String  r = "^geo:([-+]?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?),([-+]?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)(?:\\?z=(\\d{1,2}))?$";
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(r);
final Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

if (m.find()) // Coincide con el regex
{
    String lat  = m.group(1),
           lon  = m.group(2),
           zoom = m.group(3);

    if (zoom == null) // Si no tiene zoom, no captura el 3er grupo del regex
    {
        zoom = "no tiene";
    }

    System.out.format(
        "URI:      %s%nLatitud:  %s%nLongitud: %s%nZoom:     %s%n%n",
        s, lat, lon, zoom
    );
}
else
{
    System.out.format("URI:      %s%n no es una geo URI%n%n", s);
}
```

[Demo en ideone.com](https://ideone.com/csE7lH)

Comment: Gran por explicación detallada para entender las expresiones regulares, es una cosa que me cuesta mucho de crearlas con éxito